# QRC rescource file in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2013

I have got 1.2.3 Visual Studio Add-IN (QT) and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

And First i cant manually add QRC file (solution -> add -> new item - there is any QT files/items etc..)

I can add QT5CLASS (solution -> add -> class )

I generate my project and there are (in solution explorer)

1. qrc_file.cpp which is show in "generated files"
2. file.qrc in Rescource Files

I cant open this second file (file.qrc) 
I try open, open with and select QT Rescource Editor, and nothing gonna happen.

Comment: I encountered this as well. The visual studio 1.2.4 doesn't work with VS 2012. The qt folks really should test their VS addin before releasing. The quality is horrible.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the .qrc file in visual studio as an XML document. When you do 'right click -> open with...', select the option 'XML (Text) Editor' and click the 'Set as Default' button.

I actually prefer this approach to the resource editor because it's easier to add file aliases.